# Why does wantarray return in scalar context when calling foo() || die?

Tags: perl, list

I've just spent a bunch of time debugging an issue that I've traced back to `wantarray()`.  I've distilled it down to this test case.  (Ignore the fact that `$!` won't have any useful info in this scenario). What I'd like to know is why `wantarray` does not think it's being called in LIST context in the second example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

{
    my ( $one, $two ) = foo();
    is( $one, 'a', 'just foo' );
    is( $two, 'b', 'just foo' );
}

{
    my ( $one, $two ) = foo() || die $!;
    is( $one, 'a', '|| die' );
    is( $two, 'b', '|| die' );
}


done_testing();

sub foo {
    return wantarray ? ( 'a', 'b' ) : 'bar';
}
```

The output of this test is:

```
$ prove -v wantarray.pl
wantarray.pl ..
ok 1 - just foo
ok 2 - just foo
not ok 3 - || die
not ok 4 - || die
1..4

#   Failed test '|| die'
#   at wantarray.pl line 15.
#          got: 'bar'
#     expected: 'a'

#   Failed test '|| die'
#   at wantarray.pl line 16.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'b'
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 4.
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/4 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
wantarray.pl (Wstat: 512 Tests: 4 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  3-4
    Non-zero exit status: 2
    Files=1, Tests=4,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.01 sys +  0.02 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.06 CPU)
    Result: FAIL
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it's not being called in list context. `||` imposes scalar context on its left hand side, and its left hand side in this case is the expression `foo()`.

You should write instead

```
my ( $one, $two ) = foo() or die $!;
```

The `or` operator binds even more loosely than the assignment operator, so now its LHS is the entire expression `my ($one, $two) = foo()`, and `foo`'s context is determined by the list assignment operator, and everyone is happy.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is due to the precedence of the `||` operator. Your statement is basically parsed like this:

```
my ( $one, $two ) = ( foo() || die $! );
```

The `||` puts its operands in scalar context in this case.

On the other hand, if you change `||` to `or`, which has much lower precedence, your tests will pass.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. :) It was kind of a toss-up to pick an accepted answer, but the one which @hobbs provided seems a bit clearer to me.

Answer (score 4):

Logical or (`||`) is a scalar operator, so using it will force the evaluation of `foo()` to become scalar context.

Try this:

```
my @a = 10 .. 100;
print(@a || 2), "\n";
# prints 91
```

You'd expect this to print the elements in `@a` if it wasn't because the array has been evaluated in scalar context.